# How can I fill color the tile leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

[This cite](http://coinmap.org/#/map/55.73851531/37.64538288/16) uses tiles [from here](https://cartodb-basemaps-b.global.ssl.fastly.net/#16/55.7382/37.6476), but in the initial state they are gray.

How can I fill tiles to make them look like in the example?

I use this code:

```
map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false}).setView([..., ...], 15);
L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"', {}).addTo(map);
```

**Images:**

*needful:*
[image: needful]
*original - light all:*
[image: original - light all]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this problem:

- Search for a different [tile provider](https://switch2osm.org/providers/) which serves the desired colour scheme
- [Serve your own tiles](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) after [creating your own rendering style](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/)
- Change the saturation of the tiles [on the client side using 2d canvas](https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-grayscale/)
- Substitute colours in the tiles [on the client side using 2d canvas](https://github.com/hnrchrdl/leaflet-tilelayer-colorizr)
- Apply [CSS colour filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to the tiles (by [specifying a CSS class name for the tilelayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#gridlayer-classname))
- Change the saturation and substitute colours in the tiles [on the client side using WebGL](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.GL)

The map at coinmap.org (the site mentioned in the question) uses a CSS filter (`filter:saturate(4)`) on all the tiles (on the CSS selector `.map .leaflet-tile-pane`)

Comment: Oh my God! You are the best. I spent a week looking for this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ColorFilter](https://github.com/xtk93x/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter) plug-in with `['grayscale:100%']`.

See some [Demos](https://xtk93x.github.io/Leaflet.TileLayer.ColorFilter/).